# Contact SubTypes and Display Preferences

Tags: contacts, developer, display

I'm really trying to utilize the core CiviCRM for my custom purposes by using the tools provided.  I need to have a database of dogs with specific custom fields, that are related to an owner (Contact).
I have tried adding custom fields to the Contact, and add multiple lines for dogs for the contact (Contacts can have more than one dog) but it hasn't been working as well as I would want.
I created a subType called Dogs based on Individual.  My idea was to create the Dog record, then set up a relationship with the owner/Contact.  However, since I do not actually use any of the core fields or groups for Dogs, how can I have custom Display Properties so it only shows the related Custom Fields?
Is this done using the templates?  If so, is there an example someplace that shows this?

Thanks!
Norm